# Fade from normal text to italics text smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Is there a way to make it so when my user hovers over normal text that is an anchor, the text smoothly transitions into oblique or italicized text to show it is a link (including an underline)

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do...

```
<a href="http://oldsite.com">
<p class="footertext">Take me to the old site...</p>
</a>
```

---

```
p.footertext {
font-size:12px;
padding-left:4px;
text-decoration:none; }
p.footertext:hover {
/*text:decoration: "italicize smoothly"*/ }
```

Comment: Not sure you can do that, at least not with plain CSS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 transform functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to simulate italic text. You can also use [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to get the smooth transition you're looking for.

```
.italic {
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.italic:hover {
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fQ8ad/)

Comment: Austin Brunkhorst r you copying answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798821/fade-from-normal-text-to-italics-text-smoothly

Comment: In french we call that a "mise en abîme" @Fags :D

Comment: Skewed text is quite different from italic or oblique (and is frowned upon by typographers). So this does not answer the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If it doesn't answer the question, then post your solution.

Comment: It's not a solution to the problem. My solution is the best you're going to get with it comes transitioning italic font. OP's goal was to put emphasis on text (italic), it wasn't at a typographical level.

Answer (score 4):

No. Skewed text is not the same as italicized text. An italic font is not simply a skewed font, it is completely different. You can maybe cross-fade dissolve between the two, but skewed does not give you proper italicized text.